# $timeout in inside the foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, foreach, timeout

I Want to simulate player and move him using the reading below

```
$scope.playerPositions =
             [
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 180, top: 19, heading: 90 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 185, top: 19, heading: 100 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 190, top: 19, heading: 110 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 195, top: 19, heading: 120 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 200, top: 19, heading: 130 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 205, top: 19, heading: 140 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 210, top: 19, heading: 150 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 215, top: 19, heading: 160 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 220, top: 19, heading: 170 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 225, top: 19, heading: 180 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 230, top: 19, heading: 190 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 235, top: 19, heading: 200 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 240, top: 19, heading: 210 },
                 { playerId: 2028, left: 245, top: 19, heading: 220 }
                 ];
```

and Loop on every Readings

```
angular.forEach(reading, function (value, key) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope[value.playerId].pos.left = value.left + "px";
                        $scope[value.playerId].pos.top = value.top + "px";
                        $scope[value.playerId].heading = value.heading;
                    }, 1000);
                });
```

first time the loop and $timeout function is hitting correct. but the `foreach` continuously start the 2nd,3,rd looping without wait for the delay.

Comment: What is the matter with your current code? You don't list your problem.

Comment: $timeout doesn't work it's delay forEach once and want it in every reading to delay one second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `$timeout` to regularly call the angular.forEach, it won't work unless you chain the `$timeout` with its promise like below. Make sure your angular version is latest

```
let promise = $timeout();
angular.forEach(reading, function(value, key) {
     promise = promise.then(function() {
          $scope[value.playerId].pos.left = value.left + "px";
             $scope[value.playerId].pos.top = value.top + "px";
             $scope[value.playerId].heading = value.heading;
         return $timeout(1000);
     });
});
```

You can achieve the same using `setInterval` function, which will call the function regularly at the interval of 1 second.

```
function wantedLooping() {
         angular.forEach(reading, function(value, key) {

             $scope[value.playerId].pos.left = value.left + "px";
             $scope[value.playerId].pos.top = value.top + "px";
             $scope[value.playerId].heading = value.heading;

         });
     }
     setInterval(function() {
         wantedLooping()
     }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution you provided worked, you saved my day

Comment: How to Stop and Pause this Promise thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lodash in your project then it becomes very easy

```
_.debounce(() => {

    console.log('do something after 500ms');

}, 500);
```

If you want to use Observables then you can use debounceTime https://v4.angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#observables